# How to publish .NET "Release" artifact?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

What do I need to specify for the root file/folder in publish task for MSBuild "Release"?

[image: MSBuild]

Is the .NET release basically the binaries? Because for AngularOutput build I had to specify path of the AngularOutput, but for .NET Release, I am not sure what path that would be, I would think it's the entire project, which means... it's the binaries?

[image: binaries]

Expected artifact:

[image: expected]

### Update

Resulting artifact following Kevin's YAML:

[image: root]

Inside _PublishedWebsites:

[image: inside]

### Update 3

When running on Windows agent:

[image: windows]

### Update 4

Using VSBuild:

```
steps:
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: '.Net build | Build solution'
  inputs:
    solution: 'Project123/*.csproj'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: AnyCPU
    configuration: Release
    msbuildArchitecture: x64
```

Result is the same, placed in long path:

[image: VS]

### Update 5

Using `/p:PublishProfile=Project123.pubxml` MSBuild arg instead, and running on windows agent, the build completes just fine but this time. I get this warning for Publish Task:

> ##[warning]Directory 'D:\a\1\a' is empty. Nothing will be added to build artifact 'Release'.

I tried adding `/p:OutputPath=$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)` to the MSBuild args alongside the publish profile arg, and the result is the same one I posted before:

[image: result2]

Actually do we even need `/p:DeployOnBuild=true`? I understand that is to deploy, but I don't think we want or should deploy yet in the pipeline because we have a Release for that specifically to deploy the published artifacts to the App Service.

Comment: Hi @Cataster. Based on my test, the output content is related with the msbuild argument. Please refer to my update 3 and check if it could make some changes

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT I updated the pipeline with update3 yaml, so i disabled the archive, added the MSBuild arguments as suggested, and modified pathToPublish `$(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip` -> `$(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`. However, no artifact was produced this time. got the following warning: `##[warning]Directory '/home/vsts/work/1/a' is empty. Nothing will be added to build artifact 'Release'.`

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT I tested it on windows agent, and it looks like it did produce something unlike linux agent however, the path is very long. the contents are not exactly at the root. This could be why in linux agent it was not able to find anything i suppose per my comment above. so even on windows its not exactly a match with the expected artifact

Comment: Could you please try to use the VS Build task to run the same arguments on Microsoft-Hosted agent? On the other hand , based on our previous discussion, you could add the `/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=xxxx` to the build arg to use the publish profile. Please check if it could make some changes

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT please see my updates 4 & 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What do i need to specify for the root file/folder in publish task for MSBuild "Release"?

When you use the Msbuild task to build your project, the output file will be saved at the **Bin folder** by default. For example: `$(build.sourcesdirectory)/Projectname/bin`.

Based on the structure of your project, the specific path could be different.

I suggest that you could add msbuild arguments(e.g. `/p:OutputPath=$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)`) in the Msbuild task.

For example:

[image]

In this case, you could set a specific path as the output path. This will make it easier for you to Archive and Publish artifacts.

**Update:**

Ubuntu agent:

If I don't set the msbuild arg, the output files will show in the bin folder:

[image]

When I add the msbuild arg, it will upload the files to the target path:

[image]

They have the same artifacts contents.

**Update2:**

You could try the following sample to create the package for Azure APP service.

Classic :

[image]

Yaml:

```
steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Use NuGet 4.4.1'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 4.4.1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet restore'
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: Sample.sln

- task: MSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution Sample.sln'
  inputs:
    solution: Sample.sln
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: Release
    msbuildArguments: '/p:OutputPath=$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Update3:**

```
steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Use NuGet 4.4.1'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 4.4.1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet restore'
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: Sample.sln

- task: MSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution Sample.Web/Sample.Web.csproj'
  inputs:
    solution: Sample.Web/Sample.Web.csproj
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: Release
    msbuildArguments: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'


- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

Comment: I see, but do MSBuild args work when running on Ubuntu agent? I ran it today with a buncha options including MSDeploy and Setting package but i feel like it had no effect...

Comment: Hi @Cataster. For the argument:`/p:OutputPath=$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)` Based on my test, the build arg could pass the output files to the correct path . It could work as expected on Ubuntu agent.

Comment: I realize in one of the images that this is a netcore app. does this work same way for .NET Framework app? (Not .NET Core)

Comment: @Cataster Got it will test it and check

Comment: Thanks Kevin. thats one of the main issues I was having, especially because theres no documentation on .NET Framework apps (theres only on dotnetcore). I had to trial and error to get something going today. btw, i uploaded an image of expected artifacts based on manual build we do and thats what gets deployed to Azure App Service.

Comment: Hi @Cataster. The arg /p:OutputPath=$(build.artifactstagingdirectory) is also supported for .Net FrameWork. It has the same behavior.

Comment: You could refer to my update about the steps to create the Webapp package. Use Msbuild to output files to $(build.artifactsdirectory) and archive it. Then only upload the zip file as artifacts.

Comment: I see! Whats `$(Parameters.solution)`? Is that a predefined variable? and whats its value?

Comment: oh.. sorry . I made changes based on the template. So it has these variable.  This is unnecessary.  I have changed it now. This is the sln file path.

Comment: I see thanks. Btw, I was having issues when i started this pipeline with .sln, so i have been using .csproj instead. I forgot the reason/issue but would that have any impact on the output or would .csproj be same as .sln?

Comment: It should have the same output. So the behavior should be the same. You just need to change the sln file to csproj file . Then it still could work.

Comment: gotcha. and i have been using `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` in the pathtopublish. does that matter compared to `$(build.sourcesdirectory)`. does that matter which i use? I noticed they both yielded the same results

Comment: I think that this doc could answer your question. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml  They could be the same folder

Comment: Thanks. What is the value you have for `Archive File to Create` in Archive task? is it `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip` same as pathtopublish in publish task?

Comment: Yes. Then it will create a zip folder in the $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) .To avoid uploading redundant files， I use the directly push the zip file as artifacts in the  PublishBuildArtifacts task

Comment: wait i didnt understand this part `I use the directly push the zip file as artifacts in the PublishBuildArtifacts task` could you elaborate please?

Comment: Since you need to push the package to Azure App Servic， you could just upload the packaged zip file. Then you could directly use the zip file in Azure App service deployment task.

Comment: If you want push all output files to artifacts, you could set the path as `$(build.sourcesdirectory)`.

Comment: actually thats something else I wanted to ask you about. but before we get to it, i just ran this and it archived 159 files which is a great sign, but the publish task failed: `Publishing build artifacts failed with an error: Not found PathtoPublish: /home/vsts/work/1/s/249.zip`. This is what I have for my archive task and for publish task: `- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    includeRootFolder: false`

Comment: publish task: `- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: Release'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.sourcesdirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    ArtifactName: Release`

Comment: Okay. Got it. You need to change the path `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip` Sorry this is my input error.

Comment: ok so i just ran it and it ran successfully thank you :). please take a look at the photos i posted under update. i think its great but the structure is different than what we generate when building manually (see expected result photo). Like for example, the Bundles, which contains AngularOutput is missing, instead showing Angular directory. and theres also files like Web.Debug.Config that we dont need...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230395/discussion-between-cataster-and-kevin-lu-msft).